javascript call php script from different directory
I have a js script that calls a php script that is located in a different directory
$.post('../assets/php/add.php', ......

What is the right syntax for the above?
Thank you
Having both .js and .php in the same directory everything works fine
directory structure
route
en/file.html
assets/js/file.js
assets/php/file.php


It does not matter what the URL of the js file is, the URL of the html document in which that js file loaded is relevant. The URL you pass to $.post( in combination with the URL of the HTML document has to result into a URL that would point to the PHP file.

if both .php file and html file that loads the js file are on the same directory there is no problem. When I place the .php file in a directory under the html file, still no problem. The problem is when I try to go up one directory.

@NikosHalkidiki: What is the complete URL of the PHP file being invoked?  What is the complete URL of the page executing this code?  What is the complete URL being requested when it performs this AJAX request?  (You can observe the last one in your browser's debugging tools.)

What does your server configuration look like?

I have posted  file structure in initial post above, thank you

If that code is in file.js then try '../php/add.php'.
